# Angular2 (Angular.io) AOT deployment to IIS 8

Tags: angular, iis-8, windows-server-2012, angular2-aot

I have modeled a somewhat simple application following the steps outlined via the Angular.io Tour of Heros example.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

I have also implemented AOT compilation based on this example:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Pretty standard stuff straight from the Angular.io website.

On my development machine the JIT version of the application runs fine with the lite server.
On my development machine the AOT version of the application runs fine with the lite server.

Yeah!!! The world makes sense!  OK. Now its time to move the application to my 2012/IIS 8 development server.  Of coarse there are no directions for doing this specific task on the Angular.io website so I must make some assumptions.

1. All I have to do is copy the contents of the aot folder (based on the aot expmple) to my development server.
2. Since I am no longer using the lite server, I do not need to copy the bs-config.json file.
3. The package has been converted to js, css and html files.  IIS will know how to process everything (I hope, I see some map extensions in there too. I'm scared).

Sure enough. I move the files to my dev server.  It does not work.  I'm not sure if its due to some step I need to complete for aot to work on IIS, if it is something simple or both. I get the dreadful "unexpected token" error.  When I click the error link it takes me to where my build.js file is referenced in my index.html.

[image]

[image]

I assume this related to IIS since it runs fine on my local machine using the lite server.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Everything gets bundled in to build.js, so copying across the app or aot folder is redundant.  You really only need index.html, build.js, shim.min.js, zone.min.js, and your css files.  It looks to me like there could have been an error with rollup.  Did your build.js size come out larger than 0?

Comment: Thank you for your response:build.js is 697KB.  Not sure if it helps, but, I can run the built application on my local machine using the lite server.  The build process does not report any errors just the "'this' keyword" warnings as per the aot example.

Answer (score 1):

**Found the answer**

I think the problem stems from the application being located within a virtual directory on the web server. It is in a virtual directory named dashboard.  So... I had to make the following changes to index.html to get this to work:
Change `<base href="/">` To `<base href="/Dashboard">`

Change file references `<script src="dist/build.js">` to `<script src="Dashboard/dist/build.js">`

Full index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/Dashboard">
    <title>My Dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Dashboard/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="dashboard/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Dashboard/zone.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.module='aot';</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
  <script src="Dashboard/dist/build.js"></script>
</html>
```

Hopefully this helps some other poor lost soul. Problems are not over, now I will deal with the refresh/not found issue.  Good news is there seems to be plenty out there about that...